# Configure nginx to server index from subfolder

Tags: nginx

I installed a nginx webserver locally. The web root is under /var/www

Now I have a project which looks like this:
/var/www
  /test-project
    /src
    /tests

The `src` folder is the folder, which contains the `index.php` file. Now I want to run the site when I enter `https://localhost/test-project` into the browser.

Currently this is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen          443;
    server_name     localhost;
    root            /var/www/;

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default-ssl.access.log  main;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ssl/localhost.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
    }

    location ~ /test-project { #/(?!Templates|uploads).* {
        try_files $uri/ $uri/ /test-project/src/index.php?$args;
        include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;
}
```

But currently I always get redirected to the 404 page. Can anybody tell me what I have to change to get it running?

Comment: Have you tried adding `alias /var/www/test-project/src` to the test-project location?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your root as is and assuming that the full path of your `src` folder is `/var/www/test-project/src`

I would then update the location for the test-project route to:

```
location /test-project/ {
    try_files $uri /test-project/src/index.php;
}
```

If your `src` folder's full path is: `/var/www/src`, then it would be:

```
location /test-project/ {
    try_files $uri /src/index.php;
}
```

Comment: I still get an error message: `*1 directory index of "/var/www/test-project/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /test-project/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`
But I tried to add a new root to the location or to add an alias. But non of them did work.

Comment: a 403 error? If so there are some instructions in that article: [403 errors](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/403-forbidden-nginx) such as a `chmod 755` on the directory

Answer (score 0):

Web root should be /var/www/test-project, as you are saying index.php is in src, and then go for https://localhost/src, also check your permissions and ownership.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your root should point to the folder where the index is located, otherwise you're doing (in my opinion) something wrong.

Comment: how would it look if i have different projects in the same folder /var/www